# How to Route to Sibling Routing Module From Component with Separate Routing Module

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-routing, angular-module

Most routing documentation and questions seem to refer to projects that have simple component mappings, though all of my components have a corresponding routing module. I'm struggling to navigate to sibling routing modules.

Given the following architecture, I'm in Selection Component, and trying to programmatically redirect to Overview Module

I have a Layout Routing Module that contains:

```
const routes: Routes = [


{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/selection',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'budget', loadChildren: () => BudgetModule },
      { path: 'procurement', loadChildren: () => ProcurementModule },
      { path: 'team', loadChildren: () => TeamModule },
      { path: 'overview', loadChildren: () => OverviewModule },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: TopNavbarOnlyLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'selection', loadChildren: () => SelectionModule }
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],

  imports: [
    FontAwesomeModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],

  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

My Selection Module then imports SelectionRoutingModule, which looks like:

```
const routes: Routes = [


{ path: '', component: SelectionComponent }
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class SelectionRoutingModule { }
```

So if I'm in selection.component.ts, how can I route to Overview Module? All efforts thus far have resulted in the error: Cannot match any routes

Comment: Have you tried `router.navigateByUrl('/overview')` or `<button routerLink="/overview">`?

Comment: I've tried the first without luck. I need to complete some other actions first (which is why I'm hoping to do it programmatically, rather than in the element)

Comment: oops, looks like I had an extra <a> tag that mapped to a bad value, that was overriding the router call

Comment: So it does work without that `<a>` tag? :D..

Comment: Like a charm, thanks!